# Миниатюра на jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день. Возможно ли изменение размера изображения на стороне клиента перед загрузкой на сервер? Очень хороший этому пример можно посмотреть на [github](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/). При загрузке изображения появляется миниатюра, а потом можно загружать, можно не не загружать. Интернет около 30 мегабит, и поэтому даже на фотке в 5 мб не могу понять загружается ли к ним и обрабатывается или это у меня на компьютере все происходит.

Comment: Интернет около 30 мегабит незнаю получите ли вы ответ, но "сочуствия" точно не ждите ^.^

Comment: blueimp процессит файлы на поддерживаемых браузерах. вы можете проверить в chrome dev tools вкладка сеть какие данные передаются на сервер.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно canvas поможет. Тут в первом ответе есть пример [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303690/resizing-an-image-in-an-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery File Upload — строит предпросмотр на клиенте, также умеет [ресайзить](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Upload-multiple-resolutions-of-one-image-with-multiple-resize-options) и результат загружать на сервер. Но этот плагин работает только в современных бразуерах + после ресайза качество оставляет желать лучшего.

Answer (score -1):

Средствами JS на клиентской стороне подобные манипуляции с файлами невозможны. Если я все-таки ошибаюсь, буду безмерно счастлив услышать об этом!

Comment: Ты ошибаешься